# How can I reduce the cyclomatic complexity of this method

Tags: java

```
private boolean checkForNameAndAmbigousInfo(final Attribute<NonSpatialObject> od,
        final Attribute<NonSpatialObject> od1) {

        if (isNameMatching(od, od1, getModel().FEATURES.SignpostInfo.OtherDestination)
            && (isAmbigous(od) && isAmbigous(od1)))
            return true;
        if (isNameMatching(od, od1, getModel().FEATURES.SignpostInfo.OtherDestination)
            && (!isAmbigous(od) && !isAmbigous(od1)))
            return true;
        if (isNameMatching(od, od1, getModel().FEATURES.SignpostInfo.OtherDestination)
            && (isAmbigous(od) && !isAmbigous(od1)))
            return true;
        if (isNameMatching(od, od1, getModel().FEATURES.SignpostInfo.OtherDestination)
            && (!isAmbigous(od) && isAmbigous(od1)))
            return true;

        return false;

    }

private boolean isAmbigous(final Attribute<NonSpatialObject> currSignInfo) {
        final DictionaryRangeItem ambiAttribute =
            getToolkit().getDictionaryTools().getDictionaryRangeItemFromComposite(currSignInfo,
                getModel().FEATURES.SignpostInfo.AmbiguousInfo);

        return ambiAttribute.equals(getModel().RANGES.AmbiguousInfo.Ambiguous);
    }
```

There is sonar lint issue with this method. the cyclometric complexity of this method is 13 which is greated than 10

authorized. i what should i have to do now.

Comment: Questions about optimizing running ode is better asked at [codereview.se]

Comment: FYI, you spelled ambig**u**ous wrong in several places.

Answer (score 0):

Your first operand is always identical and then you test for `A&B`, `!A&!B`, `A&!B`, and `!A&B` and return true in all cases. Without looking closer, I think your code can probably be reduced to `return isNameMatching(od, od1, …)` (because your ambiguous calls will always return `true` for at least one of the conditions).
In mathematical logic that's called a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) (a statement which is always true).

(Given that `isNameMatching` is idempotent and none of your methods have side-effects, of course).

How to come to that conclusion yourself? Extracting variables and converting to a single boolean expression might help:

```
    final boolean nameMatching = isNameMatching(od, od1, getModel().FEATURES.SignpostInfo.OtherDestination);
    final boolean ambiguous1 = isAmbiguous(od);
    final boolean ambiguous2 = isAmbiguous(od1);
    return nameMatching && ambiguous1 && ambiguous2 
            || nameMatching && !ambiguous1 && !ambiguous2
            || nameMatching && ambiguous1 && !ambiguous2
            || nameMatching && !ambiguous1 && ambiguous2;
```

As you can see, at least one of the ambiguous checks must be true (you are checking all four possibilities: TT, TF, FT, FF). If at least one or-expression is true, then the final result can only be `nameMatching && true`, which can be further reduced to simply `nameMatching`.

If you are unsure about the reasoning about the or-expressions, the common term can be extracted:

```
    final boolean nameMatching = isNameMatching(od, od1, getModel().FEATURES.SignpostInfo.OtherDestination);
    final boolean ambiguous1 = isAmbiguous(od);
    final boolean ambiguous2 = isAmbiguous(od1);
    return nameMatching &&
             (  ambiguous1 &&  ambiguous2 
            || !ambiguous1 && !ambiguous2
            ||  ambiguous1 && !ambiguous2
            || !ambiguous1 &&  ambiguous2);
```

Now it should be clear that the result can only be equivalent to `return nameMatching;`.

Answer (score 0):

Provided isNameMatching has no side-effects:

```
boolean isNameMatching = isNameMatching(od, od1, getModel().FEATURES.SignpostInfo.OtherDestination);
return (isNameMatching && (isAmbigous(od) && isAmbigous(od1)))
    || (isNameMatching && (!isAmbigous(od) && !isAmbigous(od1)))
    || (isNameMatching && (isAmbigous(od) && !isAmbigous(od1)))
    || (isNameMatching && (!isAmbigous(od) && isAmbigous(od1)));
```

The 2nd part of the condition seems like a bug. "Return true if both are unambiguous"? Seems wrong.

Probably can be

```
boolean isNameMatching = isNameMatching(od, od1, getModel().FEATURES.SignpostInfo.OtherDestination);
return isNameMatching && (isAmbigous(od) || isAmbigous(od1));
```